# Xamarin ActionBar Hide Show Tabs Issue

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am working on the ability to dynamically hide and show tabs in the ActionBar on Android using a custom TabbedRenderer.  In landscape orientation I hide the tabs because I can fit the supplemental content side by side. In portrait I show tabs so that the user can click the tab to view the supplemental content.  The renderer implements the hiding and showing by changing the ActionBar NavigationMode as follows:

```
void HideShowTabs()
{
    var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;

    if ((Element as MyTabbedPage).IsTabBarVisible)
    {
        if (actionBar.NavigationMode != ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs)
            actionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
    }
    else if (actionBar.NavigationMode == ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs)
        actionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Standard;

}
```

The problem is, when I switch from `NavigationMode = Standard` to `NavigationMode = Tabs` the tabs now overlay the title in the main Navigation bar as follows.

Starting Portrait (Good):
[image]

Then Landscape (Good):
[image]

Then back to Portrait (Bad):
[image]

Thank you for any suggestions on how to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my issue is a matter of timing.  I was triggering the hide/show in the SizeChanged event of the Xamarin Forms TabbedPage derived class (Element).  That event evaluated the screen orientation and set the IsTabBarVisible property based upon the result.

The TabbedRenderer subscribed to PropertyChanged events of the Element watching for changes to the IsTabBarVisible property.  The HideShowTabs() method above was called in the renderer when changes were detected in the IsTabBarVisible property.

The issue went away when I kept all the logic in the renderer.  Overriding OnConfigurationChanged, I check for orientation changes and hide/show tabs accordingly there using the same logic in the original HideShowTabs() method.

While this makes the renderer less flexible it solves my issue for now.  I'll have to track down a better way to time the NavigationMode change so that it renders properly.  Open to suggestions if I'm handling this all the wrong way anyway.  Thanks.

```
protected override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;

        if (Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape == Resources.Configuration.Orientation)
        {
            if (actionBar.NavigationMode == ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs)
            {
                actionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Standard;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (actionBar.NavigationMode != ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs)
            {
                actionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
            }
        }

        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```